# 2-norm of the orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

[image: 1]

So far, I've deduced that if the rank of A is n, then all the columns of A are linearly independent since A has n columns. As a result, m must be greater than or equal to n.

In the case that m = n, then A is a square matrix and we can just use matrix operations to distribute the inverse operation over the parenthesis; then we can apply the associative property and compute A*A-1 and AT-1 * AT first, eventually giving that the expression inside the norm is just the identity matrix, where the 2-norm of the identity matrix is obviously 1.

I'm having trouble for the case where m > n. I've identified that the expression inside the norm is actually the matrix of orthogonal projection, but I'm not sure if that will help me with the proof. Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

This problem is from the text of "Matrix Computations" 3rd edition by Golub after covering a section on orthogonality and SVDs for some background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You’re almost there. $\|M\|_2$ is the largest singular value of $M$, i.e., the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $M^TM$. You’ve figured out that you’re working with a projection. What do you know about the eigenvalues of a projection?

Comment: M is the expression in the norm expression, and M is a projection matrix - the eigenvalues of the projection matrix are either 0 or 1. - I'm guessing that (not sure how to show this, its been a while) then the eigenvalues of M^TM are also either 0 or 1, so the maximal eigenvalue of that matrix is the biggest singular value of M, which is 1, and the square root of 1 is 1. 

Is that really it? Thought there would be more to it; been at this problem for a while...

Comment: @Ted Note that in this case $M^TM=M$, which you can show by simply multiplying it all out. You can instead work directly with the definition of the matrix norm. Since $M\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v-M\mathbf v$ are orthogonal, you know that $\|M\mathbf v\|_2\le\|\mathbf v\|_2$, with equality when $M\mathbf v=\mathbf v$.

Comment: @Ted You made the key observation, which is that the matrix inside the norm symbol represents an orthogonal projection.

Comment: out of curiosity though, do you think there would be a method to prove this without recognizing that the the interior matrix is a orthogonal projection?

Comment: @Ted See Algebraic Pavel’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach: The matrices $XY$ and $YX$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues. Since $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is symmetric, $\|A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\|_2$ is equal to the largest eigenvalue of the argument. Now set $X=A(A^TA)^{-1}$ and $Y=A^T$ and note that $YX=I$.